# XML elements are not being added in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I need to parse an XML where inline elements are available. For eg:

```
<states>
  <state name ="Alaska" colour="#ff0000" >
    <point lat="70.0187" lng="-141.0205"/>
    <point lat="70.1292" lng="-141.7291"/>
    <point lat="70.4515" lng="-144.8163"/>
    <point lat="70.7471" lng="-148.4583"/>
    <point lat="70.7923" lng="-151.1609"/>
</state>
  <state name ="Alabama" colour="#ff0000" >
    <point lat="35.0041" lng="-88.1955"/>
    <point lat="34.9918" lng="-85.6068"/>
    <point lat="32.8404" lng="-85.1756"/>
    <point lat="32.2593" lng="-84.8927"/>
  </state>
</states>
```

I am able to display all values, but when I am trying to add them to array list then it is not adding them. Below is the code where I am parsing the XML
Code in SAX Parser:

```
// Event Handlers
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal1 = "";
        tempVal2 = "";
        Log.e("SAX Details", "localName: " + localName + " qName: " + qName
                + " name: " + attributes.getValue(0));
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")) {
            // create a new instance of state
            tempState = new States();
            tempVal1 = attributes.getValue(0);
            tempVal2 = attributes.getValue(1);
            Log.e("SAX StateDetails", "localName: " + localName + " qName: "
                    + qName + " name: " + attributes.getValue(0) + " color: "
                    + attributes.getValue(1));

        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("point")) {
            // create a new instance of point
            tempPoint = new Points();
            tempVal1 = attributes.getValue(0);
            tempVal2 = attributes.getValue(1);
            Log.e("SAX pointDetails", "localName: " + localName + " qName: "
                    + qName + " lat: " + attributes.getValue(0) + " lng: "
                    + attributes.getValue(1));
        }

    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        Log.e("SAX Details", "localName: " + localName + " qName" + qName);
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")) {
            // add it to the list
            tempState.setStateName(tempVal1); // getting Exception
            tempState.setColor(Integer.parseInt(tempVal2));// getting Exception
            states.add(tempState);

        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("point")) {
            // add it to the list
            tempPoint.setLatitude(Long.parseLong(tempVal1));// getting Exception
            tempPoint.setLongitude(Long.parseLong(tempVal2));// getting Exception
            points.add(tempPoint);

        }
        tempState.setPoints(points);// getting Exception        
        Log.e("States", "" + states.size());
        Log.e("points", "" + points.size());

    }
```

Nothing is getting added in the arrayList
Here is the sample code where setter and getter methods are implemented:
States.java

```
public class States {
    private String stateName;
    private int color;
    private ArrayList<Points> points;

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public void setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public ArrayList<Points> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(ArrayList<Points> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

}
```

Points.java

```
public class Points {

    private long latitude;
    private long longitude;

    public long getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

public void setLatitude(long latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public long getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(long longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getPointsDetails() {
    String result = latitude + ": " + longitude;
    return result;
}
```

}

Please help me how can I add these elements in the ArrayList.

Updated Code:

```
    public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        public static ArrayList<States> states;
        public static ArrayList<Points> points;
        public String tempVal1;
        public String tempVal2;
        public String tempVal3;
        public String tempVal4;
        public States tempState;
        public Points tempPoint;

        public SAXXMLHandler() {
            states = new ArrayList<States>();
            points = new ArrayList<Points>();
        }

        // Event Handlers
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // reset
            tempVal1 = "";
            tempVal2 = "";
            tempVal3 = "";
            tempVal4 = "";

            tempState = new States();
            tempPoint = new Points();

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")) {
                // create a new instance of state
                tempVal1 = attributes.getValue("name");
                tempVal2 = attributes.getValue("colour");
                tempState.setStateName(tempVal1);
                tempState.setColor(tempVal2);
                states.add(tempState);

            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("point")) {
                // create a new instance of point
                tempVal3 = attributes.getValue("lat");
                tempVal4 = attributes.getValue("lng");
                tempPoint.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(tempVal3));
                tempPoint.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(tempVal4));
                points.add(tempPoint);
            }

        }

        static int statesSize = 0;

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            Log.e("NAmes", "" + localName + " : " + qName);
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")) {
                // add it to the list
                statesSize = states.size();
                            if (statesSize == states.size()) {
                    tempState.setPoints(points);
                }
//here the size of points is displayed w.r.t states i.e., 5 and 4
                Log.e("Points size", "" + tempState.getPoints().size());

            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("point")) {
                // add it to the list
//here the size of points is displayed as zero.
Log.e("Points size", "" + tempState.getPoints().size());
                            }
            if (statesSize == states.size()) {
                points.clear();
            }

        }

        public ArrayList<States> getStates() {
            return states;
        }
    }
```

Comment: After changes the code is working fine but i need to save the point with respect to the State, but all the points are added irrespective to state. i.e., for state 'Alaska' there are 5 points and 'Alabama' have 4 points, but when I display the count of points in respective state its showing 9 (5+4) as count. How can I add points considering the States.

Comment: ok the problem is you are adding same points list in both states
add 'points = new ArrayList<Points>()' after 
'points = new ArrayList<Points>();' and it will work fine

Comment: Now I am able to get the list of points based on different states but when I am trying to set the points to State, it is being set in endElement() of 'state' element. But while coming out of the function it is not displaying the points and the size of Points ArrayList is shown '0'. I have checked all possible ways but unable to rectify. Please help me where I am going wrong.

Comment: for reference view the updated code above

Comment: i tried your code and it was showing 2 states with 9 points each

add 'points = new ArrayList<Points>();' after 'tempState = new States();
            
now its showing 2 states with 5 and 4 points respectively

Comment: I tried as you suggested but still not showing any result can you please share your code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: well i used code in above example and modified xml so that it don't throw numberformatexception and then i just added 'points = new ArrayList<Points>();' after 'tempState = new States();
  share trace if you are getting some error

Comment: I am not getting the exception but even after adding 'points = new ArrayList<Points>();' after 'tempState = new States();' I am not getting the Points specific to states

Comment: i have updated by ans with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting numberformatexception, then update latitude and longitude to double and color to String

```
class XMLParsingSAX extends DefaultHandler {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new XMLParsingSAX().parseDocument();
    }

    private void parseDocument() {

        // get a factory
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            // get a new instance of parser
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            // parse the file and also register this class for call backs
            sp.parse("NewFile.xml", this);

        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(states.toString());
        System.out.println(states.get(0).getPoints().toString());
        System.out.println(states.get(1).getPoints().toString());
    }

    Points tempPoint;
    String tempVal1;
    String tempVal2;

    States tempState;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal1 = "";
        tempVal2 = "";
        System.out.println("localName: " + localName + " qName: " + qName
                + " name: " + attributes.getValue(0));
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")) {
            // create a new instance of state
            tempState = new States();
            points = new ArrayList<Points>();
            tempState.setStateName(attributes.getValue(0));
            tempState.setColor(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(1)));
            tempVal1 = attributes.getValue(0);
            tempVal2 = attributes.getValue(1);
            System.out.println("localName: " + localName + " qName: "
                    + qName + " name: " + attributes.getValue(0) + " color: "
                    + attributes.getValue(1));

        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("point")) {
            // create a new instance of point
            tempPoint = new Points();
            tempVal1 = attributes.getValue(0);
            tempVal2 = attributes.getValue(1);
            System.out.println("localName: " + localName + " qName: "
                    + qName + " lat: " + attributes.getValue(0) + " lng: "
                    + attributes.getValue(1));
        }

    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("localName: " + localName + " qName" + qName);
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")) {
            // add it to the list
//            tempState.setStateName(tempVal1); // getting Exception
//            tempState.setColor(Integer.parseInt(tempVal2));// getting Exception
            states.add(tempState);

        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("point")) {
            // add it to the list
            tempPoint.setLatitude(Long.parseLong(tempVal1));// getting Exception
            tempPoint.setLongitude(Long.parseLong(tempVal2));// getting Exception
            points.add(tempPoint);

        }
        tempState.setPoints(points);// getting Exception        
        System.out.println("" + states.size());
        System.out.println("" + points.size());

    }


       ArrayList<States> states = new ArrayList<States>();
       ArrayList<Points> points = new ArrayList<Points>();

}


 class States {
    private String stateName;
    private int color;
    private ArrayList<Points> points;

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public void setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public ArrayList<Points> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(ArrayList<Points> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "States [stateName=" + stateName + ", color=" + color + "]";
    }


}


 class Points {

        private long latitude;
        private long longitude;

        public long getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

    public void setLatitude(long latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public long getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(long longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getPointsDetails() {
        String result = latitude + ": " + longitude;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Points [latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude
                + "]";
    }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have initializing the 'state' whenever the Element tag name is "state" similarly for 'point'. Instead of that I have initialized them out of the 'if' condition, now working fine.

Comment: After changes the code is working fine but i need to save the point with respect to the State, but all the points are added irrespective to state. i.e., for state 'Alaska' there are 5 points and 'Alabama' have 4 points, but when I display the count of points in respective state its showing 9 (5+4) as count. How can I add points considering the States.